# How does packing work when marshalling?

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have this structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
unsafe struct MyStruct_t
{
    public UInt32 ulID;
    public fixed Byte xValue[32];
}
```

and then i run this command to get the size:

```
Console.WriteLine("Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct_t))= {0}", Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct_t)));
```

and the answer is consistently

```
Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct_t))= 36
```

I was expecting 40. Am i missing something? Is there something i do not understand in the meaning of Pack=8?

Comment: If Pack is set to 8, the size of the structure is the still same as in the default case, because the `ulID` field aligns on a 4-byte boundary, which is smaller than the 8-byte boundary specified by the Pack field.

Comment: so the Pack field simply gets ignored in this case?

Comment: It dictates when the runtime gives up trying to keep a member aligned because it is too large.  The UInt32 takes 4 bytes and the fixed buffer aligns to 1 since its element type is byte.  So there never is any padding required between the two members, the buffer always aligns correctly.   Padding at the end is used to ensure that the members are still aligned when the struct is stored in an array.  Never required either since it the total size happens to be a multiple of 4 so the UInt32 is always aligned.  So Pack doesn't matter at all in this case. .

Comment: But it otherwise isn't arbitrary, it must always match the packing that was used in the native code.  8 is the default for a C or C++ compiler, you'd see a #pragma or a wonky compile option (/Zp) to make it different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The fields of a type instance are aligned by using the following rules:
>
> - The alignment of the type is the size of its largest element (1, 2, 4, 8, etc., bytes) or the specified packing size, **whichever is smaller**.

You have a `Pack=8`, but your largest size element is 4 (the `UInt32`). The lesser of 8 and 4 is 4.

If you want your struct to be 40 bytes, you'll have to add 4 bytes of "padding".

Comment: You can also set the Size field of the attribute to 40 to have the compiler automatically pad it to 40 bytes.

Comment: @JoeSewell Yes, although it will only add the padding at the end. If you want the array to be aligned on an 8-byte boundary, you need to add the padding yourself between the fields.